# ldapsearch on 389-ds for persistent search

Tags: ldap, persistent

I want to test persistent search on 389-ds. But when I install it using:

```
yum install 389-ds
```

I don't get any utils like ldapsearch, ldapadd.
I've got ldapsearch from OpenLDAP installation in /usr/bin/ldapsearch
but it doesn't support -C option hence I can't test the persistent search.

From what I understand 389-ds is the same as Red Hat Directory Server and the documentation for the later says:

```
Red Hat Directory Server uses Mozilla LDAP tools, including ldapsearch. The
MozLDAP tools are installed with Directory Server and are located in the 
/usr/lib64/mozldap directory for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 (64-bit), and in
the /usr/lib/mozldap directory on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 (32-bit). When 
running any LDAP command, make sure to use the MozLDAP utilities, otherwise 
the command will return errors.
```

Now, my question is, should I get a proper ldapsearch with 389-ds installation? Or am I doing something wrong? Maybe 389-ds 1.2.2 is too old?

And the most important:
How can I get ldapsearch that allows me to use persistent search?

Versions I use:

389-ds 1.2.2-1.el6

System: CentOS 6

Comment: The tool used for persistent search should not be an issue. (I use the OpenDJ tools) You should be able to tell if the server supports the control by checking for  2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.3 in the supportedControl attribute within the rootDSE.

Comment: Thanks, OpejDJ's ldapsearch allows to perform persistent search and this is what I needed. I knew that my server supports this functionality I just lacked proper ldapsearch tool.